# How much share do the venture capitalists want if they invest in our website?

Tags: shares

I want to start a website.For that I am looking for some venture capitalists.But I have no clarity that how much share do they want in my website.Does anyone know this?Do the venture capitalists want share more than 15%?

Comment: Depends what your website may be worth, I'd suppose. How much equity are they putting in  (what percentage of the total capital)? A venture capitalist will tell you how much they want if they invest, it isn't a set global rule.

Comment: If ours is a start up and the venture capitalists invested the whole money,then how much shares could they want?

Comment: They could want as much as they want. If they're bank rolling the whole project, they'll likely want at least 51%.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about starting a business are not about personal finance. The FAQ covers what is on topic here if there are further questions.

Comment: http://startups.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate SE.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked with venture capitalists on a few different online based tools.  There is no rule.  I have seen deals go through for as little as 10% and up to 80%.

There are a number of factors in place:

- the originality of your idea
- the originality of your tech
- your current user base and expected growth
- the human assets at your company (I have seen deals go through because a company wants to work with one guy)
- the domain you own (I have seen horrible ideas get funding because they have lucrative domain name)
- revenue areas and projections (there is a huge difference in a site that brings in lots of users and generates money based on ads vs. a site that relies more on users paying)

What it really comes down to in the tech world is "Is this a side job or your life and can you live while your site isn't generating income... and then can you pay others that you need to pay for your site to exist?"

Venture capitalists are into risky ventures that offer a high return.  They have a portfolio of businesses and one going down will be made up for with a huge return on another.  They will shut you down super quick though if they think your team/idea is a dud.  What they initially take from your business is so negotiable there is no reason for me to give a number.  We might be able to give you a half-assed forecast if you tell us your idea/staff size/current revenue and expenses/projections/amount of investment looking for.

Comment: If they invest 20 crores how much share do they(venture capitalists) want?

Comment: They would want 20 crores worth of shares. (1 crore is somewhere around $156,000 USD for anyone interested).